# How to expand the verb 불러일으키시였습니다?

Tags: verb, north-korean

How can I understand the verb 불러일으키시였습니다?
As I see, it consists of 부르다 and is in past honorific form. How can I recognize the second component? I cannot find any form containing 일으키 in the vocabulary.
As I guess, it can be understood as "he inspired", but I cannot find the exact meaning part by part.

Comment: The spelling isn't standard, or it's from North Korea. The South Korean spelling would be 불러일으키시었습니다, with 었 instead of 였.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

불러일으키다 has a past-honorific form 불러일으키시였습니다.

불러 = call, 일으키다 = wake up so that 불러일으키다 means taking other's spirit, behaviour or state.

His offer is not my interest.

그의 제안은 내 관심을 불러일으키지 않는다.

The dinner brings a nostalgia to me.

그 저녁은 내게 향수를 불러일으킨다.

Answer (score 1):

불러일으키셨습니다 would make more sense and sounds right if I have to say.. rather than 불러일으키시었습니다. However, it's basically the same meaning. When 시었습니다 needs to be used, people rather use 셨습니다 instead, because it'shorter and people don't speak 시었습니다 in general during the talk or speak.